# Exact catchup point between SGH and FGH of ordinals?

Tags: computability, order-theory

An *ordinal hierarchy* is a way to assign a function $f_{\alpha} : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ to each (recursive) ordinal $\alpha$. The corresponding functions are expected to be monotone and correspond to even faster growth rates as the ordinal increases.

Two well-known definitions in the field are the *slow-growing hierarchy* $(g_{\alpha})$ and the *fast-growing hierarchy* $(h_{\alpha})$. Although the latter grows much faster than the former, some authors have claimed the existence of a 'catch-up' point, i.e. that both hierarchies attain the same growth rate at some large ordinal $LN_0$ - the notation is mine, and we have the expected relations $\epsilon_0 < FS_0 < BH_0 < LN_0$ where $FS_0$ and $BH_0$ respectively denote the Fefermann-Schütte and the Bachmann-Howard ordinals.

Specifically, it seems that S.S. Wainer first claimed that $LN_0 = FS_0$, then [retracted](http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displayAbstract?fromPage=online&aid=9079915) its claim after J.Y. Girard [proved](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0003484381900164) that $LN_0$ corresponded to the ordinal of the theory $ID_{<\omega}$. I have two questions in this respect:

(1) is this ordinal $LN_0$ canonical, or does it depend on the choice of a fundamental sequences for the hierarchies?

(2) does there exist an ordinal notation system for the ordinals up to $LN_0$? It seems that the most generic ONS known is tree-based and is due to Takeuti (?) but it's unclear to me whether it reaches $LN_0$...

Comment: Shouldn't this be on [Math Overflow](http://www.mathoverflow.net)?

Comment: @DavidRicherby, I think this one is fine here.

Comment: For question (2) look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_analysis; several notation systems are indicated for $\mathit{ID}_{<\omega}$.  I would add another one by Stan Wainer in BSL: http://www.math.ucla.edu/~asl/bsl/0503/0503-004.ps